# MacBook Pro with OSX 10.6.3 (Snow Leopard) Wi-Fi network connection breaks after few minutes

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, router, networking, wireless-networking, dhcp

I have a MacBook Pro with OSX 10.6.3 (Snow Leopard). After connecting on a Wi-Fi network, the connection "breaks" after a few minutes.

What I mean by "breaking" is that all requests, whether it is loading a web page, connecting to a share folder, connecting to my local router at 192.168.0.1, or pinging anything doesn't get through (time out). When in a "break" situation, I can see in the Network Settings panel that I still have an active IP, which I can successfully ping.

I have this problem at home with a router D-Link DI-624 and at work with a D-Link WBR-2310, all with updated firmwares.

I thought DHCP was the issue. So I tried assigning a fixed IP address (192.168.0.166). It successfully connects, but after a few minutes, the connection still breaks.

The solution I'm currently using is that I disable the AirPort (on the Network icon menu in the top bar), wait a few seconds then re-enable it. It then quickly works, but the connection still breaks after a few minutes.

I tried Googling my problem but I think I can't find any good keywords !

It's my first question here, so sorry if I don't respect some rules.

Comment: I've had similar problems (all the way back to leopard) so interested in any solutions

Comment: Sometimes, after a few minutes, the connection gets back on, as if nothing happened.

Comment: The connection "break" seems to happen only after a network inactivity, even brief. If I download some large files, the connection won't break during the transfer but will likely do when the transfer is finisehd.

Comment: Adding the keyword "inactivity", I found this a guy who has the same problem : http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/01/how-i-fixed-my-dropping-wireless-airport-connection-problem-in-snow-leopard/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that **D-Link** routers are known to be incompatible with Mac. At least one shop I know stopped selling D-Link routers because they had too much complains from Mac customers.

My solution was then to **change my router**. I now have a Linksys WRT160N. So far, I never had any connection break.

Comment: Interesting. My MacBook and my D-Link DIR-655 seem to get along just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem seems related to inactivity, a solution would be to **keep a continuous Internet transfer**, for exemple opening a web radio. For instance, when I turn on my computer, I open this link [http://www.chyz.ca/lecteur-audio/webradio-hipe](http://www.chyz.ca/lecteur-audio/webradio-hipe/) and since then, I didn't have any more problems.

It is clearly not solving the problem, though. If the web radio closes its window, a connection break is likely to happen shortly after.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any information about the environment your wireless connection is in, what sort of distances you are from the router and what the signal strength is.

If the connection "drops", I would suspect interference possibly from another wireless signal or a device which spews noise onto the 2.4 MHz band such as a microwave or a cordless phone.

Can you tell us more about your workplace and home? Are they isolated or are there potential sources of interference in them?

If you really suspect the router then I would also check to see if you are using the latest firmware level for it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete /Macintosh HD/Library/Preferences/"com.apple.alf.plist." (It basically stores adhoc
   IP Configurations.
2. Restart
3. Accept connections on restart if you want to.